# PHP - pass hidden value into the jquery (part 2)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Cont on [PHP - pass hidden value into the jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35423994/php-pass-hidden-value-into-the-jquery#35424054)

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui-themes-1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".buttonsPromptConfirmDeleteDepartment").click(function(){
        $("#dialogConfirmDeleteDepartmentBox").dialog({
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            width: 300,
            height: 150,
            dialogClass: "dialogConfirmDeleteDialogBox",
            position: { my: 'top', at: 'top+300' },
            open: function() {
                var message = 'Are you sure you want to delete this department?';
                $(this).html(message);
            },
            buttons:
            [
                {
                    text: "OK",
                    click: function()
                    {
                        var departmentID = $(this).next('input.departmentID').val();
                        alert(departmentID);  
                    },
                    style:"margin-right: 60px;" 
                },
                { 
                    text: "Cancel",
                    click: function () 
                    {
                        $(this).dialog("close");  
                    }, 
                    style:"margin-left: 0px;" 
                },
            ]
        });
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<?php
//db connection

$query = "SELECT * 
          FROM department 
          ORDER BY dept_ID ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$total_department = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($total_department > 0)
{
?>

<table width="600" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse">
  <tr>
    <td width="80" align="center">ID</td>
    <td width="300" align="center">Department</td>
    <td width="220" align="center">Action</td>
  </tr>   
<?php        
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
?>
    <tr>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $row['dept_ID']; ?></td>
      <td align="center"><?php echo $row['dept_name']; ?></td>
      <td>
        <button class="buttonsPromptConfirmDeleteDepartment">Delete</button>
        <div id="dialogConfirmDeleteDepartmentBox" title="Confirm"></div>
        <input type="hidden" class="departmentID" value="<?php echo $row['dept_ID']; ?>" />    
      </td>
    </tr>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
</table> 
<?php
}
?>
```

department table

```
dept_ID     dept_name 
1           Account
2           Finance
3           Marketing
```

This time I add a dialog box inside my code.
Assume that my department table only have 3 records.
My requirement is the following:
- Click 1st delete button, show dialog box, click OK, show department ID = 1
- Click 2nd delete button, show dialog box, click OK, show department ID = 2
- Click 3rd delete button, show dialog box, click OK, show department ID = 3

However, I get undefined value no matter what button I clicked.

Can someone help me?

Comment: add id to your hidden field like "<input type="hidden" id="department" class="departmentID" value="<?php echo $row['dept_ID']; ?>" />  " and then get its value using jquery like "var val = $("#department").val();"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(this)` in

```
var departmentID = $(this).next('input.departmentID').val();
```

does not refer to your DOM object but to the current dialog.

Create a reference to your DOM object first, which you can then use later on:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".buttonsPromptConfirmDeleteDepartment").click(function(){

        var $box = $(this);

        ...
        ...

            click: function()
            {
                var departmentID = $box.parent().find('input.departmentID').val();
                alert(departmentID);  
            }

        ...
        ...

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could select the input by the class name `departmentID`, use :

```
$(this).closest('td').find('.departmentID').val();
```

Instead of :

```
$(this).next('input.departmentID').val();
```

Hope this helps.